# Modifying the prototype of an object may or may not affects these instances

Tags: javascript

This piece of code:

```
function A(){}

A.prototype = {
    a : 5
}

var b = new A();
console.log('b.a : ' + b.a);

A.prototype = {
    a : 10
}

console.log('b.a : ' + b.a);
```

produces:
b.a : 5
b.a : 5

While the piece of code below modifies the prototype for the existing instances of A:

```
function A(){}

A.prototype = {
    a : 5
}

var b = new A();
console.log('b.a : ' + b.a);

A.prototype.a = 10;

console.log('b.a : ' + b.a);
```

and produces:
b.a : 5
b.a : 10

How is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion between `prototype` and `[[prototype]]` (or `__proto__`).

The former is a (normal, non-magical) property that will get set as the latter (which is internal, and generally not to be messed with) in any object that is created from a constructor. Thus, when you do `b = new A()`, `A`'s `prototype` becomes `b`'s `[[prototype]]`. When we say that in JavaScript attributes are looked up first on the object and then up the prototype chain, it is this `[[prototype]]` that is meant.

When you change `A.prototype.a` in your second case, you changed `b`'s `[[prototype]]` at the same time (as it's the same object).

When you assign a new object to `A.prototype`, it is no longer the same object as `b`'s `[[prototype]]`. Thus, `b.a` is divorced from `A.prototype.a`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this to understand JavaScript Object Model better.

[MDN JavaScript - Details_of_the_Object_Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model)